# Sonar cloud not submitting jacoco xml coverage file

Tags: android, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarcloud, android-jacoco

I have an app with a separate module.  I am looking to combine code coverage in a single xml report and submit to sonar cloud.  I have managed to combine the coverage thanks to the help of this [blog post](https://thsaravana.github.io/blog/jacoco-single-coverage-for-multi-module/#:%7E:text=Setting%20up%20JaCoCo%20for%20Multi,gradle%20.&text=Now%2C%20you%20can%20run%20.%2F,a%20report%20for%20each%20module.).  However, I am having problems with the sonar integration.

Here is my sonar.gradle

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "*******"
        property "sonar.organization", "*********"
        property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io"
        property "sonar.token", "*********"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.projectName", "*********"
        property "sonar.sources", ["src/test", "src/main/java"]
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test"
        property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "/Users/james/Documents/Development/testapp/app/build/reports/jacoco/allDebugCoverage/allDebugCoverage.xml'."
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew sonar -info`

I can see

```
No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='/Users/james/Documents/Development/testapp/app/build/reports/jacoco/allDebugCoverage/allDebugCoverage.xml'.
```

From the screen shot we can see the `allDebugCoverage.xml` is there.  The html provides a visual on the expected coverage for the code.

Then I see `Searching for` ... and it lists each of my test classes.

The rest of the analysis is taking place, the test coverage is not being submitted.

I am sure I am doing something stupid here,  there is very little clear up to date guidance on this.  If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

[image: Path to allDebugCoverage.xml]

Comment: Try a relative path: `build/reports/jacoco/allDebugCoverage/allDebugCoverage.xml`. I use Maven and use a relative path.

Comment: @Bademeister thank you for coming back to me.. even whittling down the path to a relative one it still states it can't be found.

Comment: "No coverage report can be found with ..." could it be no, that it is not a report at all? For me, the file is called jacoco.xml. The root element in the file is `<report>`. Remove `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`. Sonar will then show you various search paths in log output. My config: 
`mvn ... -Dsonar.java.source=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml`

Comment: My thought process was it doesn't matter what the file is called, once you have the correct path to it.  I can check the config

Comment: Yes, the name does not matter. Maybe you are including a file that is not a report file. Therefore, I would leave out the property and see what files Sonar itself looks for.

Comment: @Bademeister ah yes I understand.  Omitting the path doesn't work I'm afraid, just throws this


`'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer`

Comment: Sonar looks for report files on a standard configured jacoco. Please check if allDebugCoverage.xml is a report file. Of course you have to specify `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`. I have seen which file is needed by omitting it with my [default configuration](https://github.com/alaugks/spring-messagesource-xliff/blob/dd2157dde5a4c33564451ddb1596b73d3e6c7e99/pom.xml#L237), `target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml` existed.

Comment: @here is there no one that can steer me in the right direction?>